Integral $\int_x^{2\pi}\tan(u)\, du$ can be computed for which $x$?
Computing
$$
\int_x^{2\pi}\tan(u)\, du
$$
one can use that
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(-\ln(\cos x))=\tan(x)
$$
so that
$$
\int_x^{2\pi}\tan(u)\, du = \ln(\cos(x))
$$
But I am wondering for which $x$ this is true, probably for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ which are no zeros of the cosine, i.e., $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}: k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$?
Or just for those $x\in\mathbb{R}$ for which there exists no zero of cosine in $[x,2\pi]$, which would mean for $x=\frac{3}{2}\pi$ only?

On the largest interval around $2\pi$ on which $\cos x$ remains $>0$, i.e. $(2\pi-\pi/2,2\pi+\pi/2)$.

Presuming Cauchy Principal Value, for all $x$.

There is a mistake in the Approach. It will be $-\ln|\cos(x)|$ and not $\ln(\cos(x))$. Because $\int\frac{1}{x}dx$ is $\ln|x|+C$ and not $\ln(x)+C$

Why my Answer is downvoted  ?
